# Do I need a .h for a class with only a main method in C++

Tags: c++

I need to create 2 classes, with their respective .h and .cc, and then another class with a main, let's call them A, B and C, being the C class the one with the main.

Given that the C class is used only to contain that main and doesn't need either instance or class variables, or other methods, do I need to create C.h or with C.cc it's enough?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. `int main()` is not part of any class in C++.

Comment: "Given that the C class is used only to contain that main" ? Are you confusing it with Java? In C++ `main` is a free function

Comment: So your actual `main` function is only `int main() { C c; c.main(); }`? Ask the person that needs you to create these what you are required to do. There are no other needs than those.

Comment: int main() needs to be a free function in the global namespace. It won't be recognized as the c++ main function if it is a class member.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well technically, you don't *need* headers ever, you could simply copy-paste declarations in every `.cpp` files.

If you don't need a declaration in any other file, I'd suggest this is a good practice to place it in the relevant `.cpp` file to keep it private. This can be couple with a `namespace { ... }` or declare them as static (static as in private to translation unit). This hides irrelevant details from your header code, and prevent misuse of private functions and private variable that should only be used in one `.cpp` file.

Comment: Are there advantages or disadvantages for `static` versus `namespace { ... }` for a free function or global-to-translation-unit variable?  (Can't `static` a class declaration, of course.)

Comment: They are technically the same (for globals and free functions). It saves typing stuff since you put a whole section of code in it. However, a malicious header could declare `inline namespace { }` in the global namespace, preventing you from declaring `namespace { }` in the global namespace too, but at that point a malicious header could also define a macro that screw your code.

Comment: Maliciousness in C++ almost seems like it'd be redundant, for the same reason there are no Obfuscated Perl contests.  Damian Conway says, "C++ tries to guard against Murphy, not Machiavelli."

Answer (score 0):

`C.cc` should be enough, since you are not doing any variable declarations in that class.
You just need to include `A.h` and `B.h` through `#include` statements

Comment: I'm curious, why would doing variable declarations in that class change your answer?

Answer (score 0):

It's a good habit for organizational purposes. If your intention is to use them together as a library for the next program you build, then yes, you should, that way you'll run in less compiling issues.